# Python dependencies - how to download/install

Tags: python, dependencies

I am new to Python and today I received a Python 2 script and would like to run it. Never worked with Python, but the code looks straight forward. The issue is, that right at the beginning there is:

```
import requests, sys, os, re
import unicodecsv as csv
from lxml import html
from bs4 import UnicodeDammit
from lxml import etree
```

And I'm not sure how to install these dependencies. I googled around and figured that some 'requirements.txt' file would help, but I have not received it.

So how or whats the best way to install these dependencies please?

Comment: `pip install requests` for "requests" library

Comment: `pip install beautifulsoup4` for "bs4". `pip install lxml` for "lxml". `pip install unicodecsv` for "unicodescv"

Answer (score 0):

**Thank you for the comments.**

Looks like pip is the package manager so to speak for Python and the packages you stated worked.

```
pip install requests
pip install beautifulsoup4
pip install lxml
pip install unicodecsv
```

Thank you again!